# Rails application with utf8 html encoding and with latin1 database (ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

With the current configuration, I am getting weird characters on the browser.

Is there a way to configure ActiveRecord in order for this kind of conversion to happen automaticaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using IConv... I just needed to use this DB for some particular cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
charset: latin1
encoding: latin1
collation: latin1_general_ci
```

to your config/database.yml

Comment: Hi! I am sorry to tell that this did not work. And by the way. I forgot to mention that I am using ruby 1.8.7.